# Differences between solution files for .NET Framework and new .NET

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-7.0

I am upgrading some C# programs from old .NET Framework 3.5 to .NET 7, and got some interesting problem.

This class `System.CodeDom.CodeTypeMember` from assembly `System.CodeDom.dll` is being used in the code. And I found that after I upgraded the project to .NET 7, this class is not usable. But when I try this class in another project in .NET 7, it's usable.

Then I found a more interesting thing.

If I create a solution with creating a .NET Framework project, this class will be unavailable even if I add a new .NET 7 project in this solution.
However, if the solution is created when creating .NET 7 project, this class is available.

But I didn't found any differences between these two sln files.

Do anyone know why this happens and how to fix it?
The VS version I am using is 2022, 17.6.5.

Typo for `Syste.CodeDemo`, it should be `System.CodeDom`.

Comment: It might be helpful to see the solution and project files (relevant excerpts only). Just based on your description it's difficult to tell what is wrong.

Comment: .Net Framework 3.5 is actually .NET Framework *2*, with extra classes. The differences you ask about span 13 years. Before migrating the solution to .NET 7, are you sure you can even open it in Visual Studio and switch to .NET Framework 4.x ?

Comment: Solution files aren't specific to .NET Framework or .NET Core - the same solution can have multiple project files which target different frameworks (and then a single project file can target multiple frameworks too). But the important bits are really going to be in the project files, not the solution files.

Comment: Additionally, CodeTypeMember is in the System.CodeDom namespace - not System.CodeDemo. Details like that really matter - if you had `using System.CodeDemo;` in your code then it's no wonder it didn't work.

Comment: @JonSkeet In fact, solution files are not even specific to .NET. A solution might as well contain unmanaged C++ projects, or Wix Setup projects, or...

Comment: @JonSkeet even between VS 2008 and 2022? The OP says the original project is .NET Framework 3.5. I don't (want to) remember the possible differences to `.sln` over that period. I think it's only a version number change and  VS 2022 should be able to handle even very old version numbers.

Comment: Indeed. A solution file is just a container for project files (and separate solution-based files).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Yes, even between those. I would be really surprised if the problem were in solution files. Also note that just because they're using a .NET Framework 3.5 project doesn't mean that it was created with VS2008 - it could have been created with VS2022. Unfortunately the question doesn't provide enough details to diagnose any further.

Comment: @JonSkeet I thought System.CodeDom wouldn't even be available in .NET Core but it's available as a NuGet package, like other legacy APIs. Assuming `CodeDemo` is a typo for `CodeDom`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Yup. Basically it's all a bit confusing in the question until we can see the relevant project files...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no `System.CodeDemo` but there's `System.CodeDom`, so I'll assume this was a typo.

.NET 7 is .NET *Core* 7, a completely different, cross-platform (as in Linux on ARM, not XBOX) runtime and SDK. Microsoft decided to remove the `Core` part in .NET 5 for marketing reasons. .NET 5,6,7 and 8 though are .NET *Core* 5,6,7,8.

`System.CodeDom` isn't part of .NET Core itself, it's essentially a compatibility package available through the [System.CodeDom](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.CodeDom) NuGet package.

One of the reasons for this is that it wasn't very popular. It was too cumbersome so it was largely replaced by [Source Generators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview) and analyzers through the new (for 2010) [Roslyn compiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/).

Most of the generators and analyzers you use in Visual Studio nowadays (except Resharper) use Roslyn.

.NET Core-compatible NuGet packages (.NET Core or .NET Standard) that require CodeDom specify  a dependency on the package, so this isnt' an issue.

Comment: Thanks and I found the package in NuGet manager. But it's still very interesting that I can use this class directly in a .Net 7 project, and I never install this package.

Comment: Thank you so much, and I finally got clear why. I installed BenchmarkDotNet fot the test project, and that has a reference to System.Management, which has reference to System.CodeDom. So, I can use this Class directly.